# Converting ID to Name with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So in my database, I've got a junction table that lists all of the "purposes" someone has for a loan. The code worked when just showing the values (in number form), but in my second loop where I search a second table for the actual name of the purpose, I'm running into issues. It displays the correct *number* of purposes, but unfortunately, the text repeats the first found purpose that number of times rather than displaying all applicable purposes.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub cmdMsgBox_Click()

Dim DB As Database
Dim tblOpp2LP As Recordset
Dim tblLoanPurpose As Recordset
Dim ctlFindRecord As Control
Dim lngHoldOpportunityID As Variant
Dim intRecordCount As Integer
Dim valTestBox As String
Dim valLP As String
Dim valName As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set tblInputOpp2LP = DB.OpenRecordset("Opp2LP")

Set tblLoanPurpose = DB.OpenRecordset("LoanPurpose")
Set ctlFindRecord = Me.ctlFindRecord


lngHoldOpportunityID = CLng(ctlFindRecord)
valTestBox = ""

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling_Err:

tblInputOpp2LP.FindFirst "[OpportunityID] = " & lngHoldOpportunityID

If tblInputOpp2LP.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No Matching Record Found"
    Exit Sub
Else
Do Until tblInputOpp2LP.EOF
    If lngHoldOpportunityID = tblInputOpp2LP![OpportunityID] Then
        valLP = tblInputOpp2LP![LPID]
        intCounter = intCounter + 1

        Do Until tblLoanPurpose.EOF
            If valLP = tblLoanPurpose![LPID] Then
                valName = tblLoanPurpose![Name]
            End If
            tblLoanPurpose.MoveNext
        Loop

        If valTestBox = "" Then
            valTestBox = valName
        Else
            valTestBox = valTestBox & ", " & valName
        End If
    End If

    tblInputOpp2LP.MoveNext
Loop

txtMsgbox = valTestBox

End If

ErrorHandling_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " - " & Err.Number
    Resume ErrorHandling_Exit
End Sub
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

As it turns out, what I needed to do was add an "exit do" in the second loop.

See the below code example.

```
Private Sub cmdMsgBox_Click()

Dim DB As Database
Dim tblOpp2LP As Recordset
Dim tblLoanPurpose As Recordset
Dim ctlFindRecord As Control
Dim lngHoldOpportunityID As Variant
Dim intRecordCount As Integer
Dim valTestBox As String
Dim valLP As String
Dim valName As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set tblInputOpp2LP = DB.OpenRecordset("Opp2LP")

Set tblLoanPurpose = DB.OpenRecordset("LoanPurpose")
Set ctlFindRecord = Me.ctlFindRecord


lngHoldOpportunityID = CLng(ctlFindRecord)
valTestBox = ""

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling_Err:

tblInputOpp2LP.FindFirst "[OpportunityID] = " & lngHoldOpportunityID

If tblInputOpp2LP.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No Matching Record Found"
    Exit Sub
Else
Do Until tblInputOpp2LP.EOF
    If lngHoldOpportunityID = tblInputOpp2LP![OpportunityID] Then
        valLP = tblInputOpp2LP![LPID]
        intCounter = intCounter + 1

        Do Until tblLoanPurpose.EOF
            If valLP = tblLoanPurpose![LPID] Then
                valName = tblLoanPurpose![Name]
                exit do
            End If
            tblLoanPurpose.MoveNext
        Loop

        If valTestBox = "" Then
            valTestBox = valName
        Else
            valTestBox = valTestBox & ", " & valName
        End If
    End If

    tblInputOpp2LP.MoveNext
Loop

txtMsgbox = valTestBox

End If

ErrorHandling_Exit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " - " & Err.Number
    Resume ErrorHandling_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Great!  I want to suggest that you rewrite that whole branch in a few lines.  You can open a record set in the following way `Set tblLoanPurpose = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM LoanPurpose WHERE LPID = " & valLP)` and then iterate through that instead of all the extra matching and ifs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This seems like it would certainly be more efficient in that it is parsing through less data, but wouldn't it still need the loops? If you submit another version of what I typed with an example of what you mean, and it works, I'd gladly mark yours as the correct answer!

Comment: So I'm running into another problem with the code now.

SOMETIMES it seems to repeat the last loan purpose it finds over and over instead of using the first then second, etc. It seems to repeat the correct number of times, just not the correct value. Thoughts? It's odd to me that it occasionally works correctly but not always.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data in your question? Just a few lines and column names etc.  Would help in understanding it better.